# Ubuntu themes won't install

Tags: unity, gnome, themes, unity-tweak-tool, icon-themes

I've try to install different themes from http://www.ubuntuthemes.org/ and after I downloaded, I've put it on my themes folder in `/usr/share/themes` but don't work, before that I've try to put in `~/.themes` but I don't know why... I don't have that folder.
And another solution I've tried has with `Unity Tweak Tool` but with this I have just few themes available and I don't know how to add more. 
So if anyone know, please show me how I can add in my Ubunut 15.04 more themes.

Thx for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have almost done.

Once you have downloaded your favourite theme (usually compressed in zip file) you should unzip the file and move the theme's directory into `usr/share/themes` directory (you'll probably need root permission).

Now you can open *Ubuntu Tweak Tool*, go to themes tab and you should see the added theme as a list entry. Select it and enjoy with the new theme.

I've tested this procedure with [Numix](https://numixproject.org/) theme, [Flatabulous](https://github.com/anmoljagetia/Flatabulous) theme and a my customized theme.